# Is there any alternative way of writing this switch statement(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

Can it be done in a better way

```
public static EnumFactorType GetFactorEnum(string str)
        {
            Standardization e = new Standardization();
            switch (str.ToLower())
            {
                case "beta":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.BETA;
                    break;
                case "bkp":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.BOOK_TO_PRICE;
                    break;
                case "yld":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.DIVIDEND_YIELD;
                    break;
                case "growth":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.GROWTH;
                    break;
                case "mean":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.MARKET_CAP;
                    break;
                case "momentum":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.MOMENTUM;
                    break;
                case "size":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.SIZE;
                    break;
                case "stat_fact1":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.STAT_FACT_1;
                    break;
                case "stat_fact2":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.STAT_FACT_2;
                    break;
                case "value":
                    e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.VALUE;
                    break;
            }
            return e.FactorType;
        }
```

If I create a Static class(say Constatant) and declare variable like

```
public static string BETA= "beta";
```

and then if I try to put that in the Case expression like

```
Case Constants.BETA : e.FactorType = EnumFactorType.BETA;
                        break;
```

then the compiler will report error.(quite expected)

So is there any other way?(I canot change the switch statement)

Using C#3.0

Thanks

Comment: If you can change the `switch` statement, use `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: @KennyTM: However, some of the strings in the switch does not correspond to the names in the enumeration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a `Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType>` as a "mapping" and use that instead. It's essentially the same logic but can be a bit more readable.

First, the mapping object:

```
private Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType> _mapping = new Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType>
{
    { "beta", EnumFactorType.BETA },
    { "bkp", EnumFactorType.BOOK_TO_PRICE },
    // etc
}
```

Then in your method:

```
e.FactorType = _mapping[str.ToLower()];
```

You may want to call _mapping.ContainsKey(str) first just to be sure the mapping exists.

Comment: Use the `TryGetValue` method instead if you need to make sure the mapping exists. Otherwise you're doing two identical lookups.

Comment: Might want to make that _mapping static though; you wouldn't want to generate one for every instance, would you?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
public const string BETA = "beta";
```

Works fine. The way you declared it, it is a variable. Variables are not allowed in `case` expressions. By using the `const` keyword, you're telling the compiler it's in fact a constant, as your class name suggests.

What do you mean by "I cannot change the switch statement"? With a sufficiently large amount of possibilities, I would consider using a Dictionary. Mind you, this would mostly be for readability and maintainability, not performance. With a Dictionary, it would be easier to do a reverse conversion for example, as you can construct a reverse dictionary from the same data.

Using a dictionary, it would look something like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType> _factorTypeMap =
new Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    { "beta", EnumFactorType.BETA },
    { "bkp", EnumFactorType.BOOK_TO_PRICE },
    // etc. You can still use strings constants here instead of literals.
};
```

Then in your method:

```
EnumFactorType factorType;
if (_factorTypeMap.TryGetValue(str, out factorType))
{
    e.FactorType = factorType;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Unexpected value, bla bla");
}
```

If you're certain the value exists, it's simpler:

```
 e.FactorType = _factorTypeMap[str];
```

Creating a reverse dictionary is a one-liner, displayed here on two lines :)

```
Dictionary<EnumFactorType, string> _factorTypeReverseMap =
    _factorTypeMap.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

The strings used in a switch have to be constant, so if you declare a constant instead of a variable, you can use it in the switch:

```
public const string BETA = "beta";
```

If you don't want the strings to be constant, so that you can change them while the program is running, you can't use a switch. Then you could use a `Dictionary<string, EnumFactorType>` to look up the values to get similar performance as a switch.

Comment: There is no point to doing this as mentioned above when he case the compiler makes this a const. We don't need to make a const because we aren't reusing this value.

Comment: @LCarter: Of course it's pointless, but it answers the question.